# Default landing Tab not updated when I upgrade a managed package

Tags: managed-package, tab, app, upgrade

I have managed package and have major release for this. This release also includes changing the default landing tab. We have changed the tab in app xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<defaultLandingTab>XYZ</defaultLandingTab>
```

This works fine with the fresh install of the package but if I upgrade the package from previous to new one the default tab is not changing. 
Is is this the limitation for managed packages in case of upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm#component_properties

Above link provides details about which components are supported in package upgrade. Hope this helps you!

Comment: :) Thanx Needhi